# Pass variable with double quotes to JSON for REST client in PERL

Tags: json, perl, double-quotes

Situation is the I am dealing  with REST and JSON. Making JSON request for a REST client. 
I have a simple for loop that creates ids for me

```
for (my $i=1;$i<=2504;$i++)
 {
   push (@elements,$i);
 }
 my $ids = join ',',map{"\"$_\""}@elements;
```

However, when I pass this to JSON then I see backslash are being printed

```
$hashref=({"varreq"=>{"search"=>{"Ids"=>[$ids],"genome"=>[{"hugo"=>["$hugo"]}]},"output_format">{"groupby"=>"gene"}}});
```

Above is encoded in JSON and then a post request is made

I am getting this:

```
  "\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",......
```

and I want:

```
  "1","2","3","4",.....
```

Comment: Which language (Coding) You are using? And you're getting problem while requesting or response?

Comment: Using perl, the query itself(request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing JSON, why not just:

```
use JSON;
```

Rather than hacking it with regular expressions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my $json_str = to_json ( [1..2504] );
print $json_str;
```

With `to_json` you can encode into a `JSON` structure pretty much any perl data structure. (and `from_json` to turn it back again).

You can do an OO style with `encode_json`/`decode_json`.

You seem to be doing this already, but ... this here:

```
{"Ids"=>[$ids],
```

Can be simply changed as the above:

```
{ "Ids" => [@elements]
```

Which should do what you want.

From the comments - I don't think anything receiving JSON should be getting confused by an array of numbers vs. an array of numeric strings.

But if they do:

```
my $json_str = to_json [ map {"$_"} 1..2504 ];
```

Comment: So i tried this: 
           ` my $json_str = to_json ( [1..2504] );`
            `print $json_str;`
and this gives me 
                       `  [1,2,3,4.....] `and in JSON all it does is `"[1,2,3,4...]"`
   I want `["1","2","3","4"......]`

Comment: Should work just the same. After all, they're only json values. But if that doesn't work `[map {"$_"} 1..2504]`

Comment: so in part using 
    `[map {"$_"}1..2504]` worked, but then the entire then again is surrounded with "". This is because of string vs numerical val in JSON. 
     dont want `"["1","2","3"]"` instead 
      `["1","2","3",....]`

Comment: Sort of, but I'd still stick with just building as JSON rather than trying to inject a JSON array as a string into your JSON objcet.

Comment: Oh I agree with you and current standard for JSON, int is without double quotes. But I not the SE who has designed this.

Comment: Non standard "standards" make me sad.

Answer (score 0):

well, after encoding but before making the POST request I end up doing the following and it worked:

```
$postRequestJSON=~s/\\//g;
```